# Android Studio navigation do not render

Tags: android, xml, gradle

I made new navigation drawer activity, then I worked on project for few days, then I customizes my navigation into this:

> ```
> <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
>     <item
>         android:id="@+id/nav_pocetna"
>         android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
>         android:title="Početna" />
>     <item
>         android:id="@+id/nav_postavi_oglas"
>         android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
>         android:title="Postavi Oglas" />
>     <item
>         android:id="@+id/nav_novo"
>         android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
>         android:title="Novo u 48h" />
>     <item
>         android:id="@+id/nav_prijava"
>         android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
>         android:title="Prijava" />
>     <item
>         android:id="@+id/nav_pretraga"
>         android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
>         android:title="Pretraga" />
>     <item
>         android:id="@+id/nav_kreiraj_nalog"
>         android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
>         android:title="Kreiraj nalog" />
> </group>
>
> <item android:title="Komunikacija">
>     <menu>
>         <item
>             android:id="@+id/nav_o_nama"
>             android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
>             android:title="O Nama" />
>         <item
>             android:id="@+id/nav_podeli"
>             android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
>             android:title="Podeli" />
>         <item
>             android:id="@+id/nav_pratite_nas"
>             android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
>             android:title="Pratite nas" />
>         <item
>             android:id="@+id/nav_kontakt"
>             android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
>             android:title="Kontakt" />
>     </menu>
> </item> </menu>
> ```

And when I go to design view I got this:
[image]
But when I launch app on my phone it works normal. What is problem?

[image]

Comment: What is your problem? Not able to understand

Comment: Your navigation drawer not showing icon is it ?

Comment: Right now navigation menu shows like the way showed up as an attachment. because you are looking it from menu directory.

Comment: I edited questio, look my phone app..